# Born in France but left at an early age: Can I obtain the French citizenship?

Tags: france, passport

I was born in France and lived there until the age of 3 then moved back to my country which is Iraq, so my question is what are the procedures that i need to follow to get the French passport if possible?

Answer (score 4):

If your parents were themselves born in France, you have been French since your birth (*double droit du sol*).

If not, there is no easy path to French citizenship. Without getting into irrelevant details, all the applicable procedures only cover people who grew up in France/spent most of their formative years in France.

Like everyone else, you can of course use the regular naturalisation procedure but that requires living in France for several years (and therefore securing a visa allowing you to do it in the first place). Being born in the country does not confer any advantage in this situation.